# Get start and end time for different periods in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have this DataFrame.

```
timestamp            Val1 
2020-04-02 06:44:00  NaN    
2020-04-03 16:52:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:53:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:54:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:55:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:03:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:04:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:05:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:06:00  NaN
```

And I trying to separate in groups using the sequence of minutes. For example, I can't group rows with more then 1 min with difference.
So the output will be like this:

```
#Group 1
timestamp            Val1
2020-04-02 06:44:00  NaN

#Group 2
timestamp            Val1
2020-04-03 16:52:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:53:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:54:00  NaN
2020-04-03 16:55:00  NaN


#Group 3
timestamp            Val1             
2020-04-17 02:03:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:04:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:05:00  NaN
2020-04-17 02:06:00  NaN
```

Now, I just can get the min and max data with all the data. But no like what I want to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the difference between consecutive rows and check whether it is above your desired difference (`'1min'`). Taking the `cumsum` of this Boolean Series creates the grouping label. I've assigned it to a column here for illustration.

```
#df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['group'] = df['timestamp'].diff().gt('1min').cumsum()

            timestamp  Val1  group
0 2020-04-02 06:44:00   NaN      0
1 2020-04-03 16:52:00   NaN      1
2 2020-04-03 16:53:00   NaN      1
3 2020-04-03 16:54:00   NaN      1
4 2020-04-03 16:55:00   NaN      1
5 2020-04-17 02:03:00   NaN      2
6 2020-04-17 02:04:00   NaN      2
7 2020-04-17 02:05:00   NaN      2
8 2020-04-17 02:06:00   NaN      2
```

Comment: When I try that, all rows in group is equal to 0